# Porque este código entra em loop infinito?

Tags: java, loop, ciclo-infinito

Porque se eu colocar uma entrada inválida como *asdf* o código abaixo entra em loop infinito?

Depois de capturar a exceção e escrever a mensagem ele não deveria pedir uma outra entrada novamente?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Leitura {
    public static void main (String[] argumentos) {
        int chute = -1, sorteado = 37;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Insira um número:");
            try {
                chute = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception excecao) {
                System.out.println("Lol, loop infinito? Sem pedir outra entrada novamente?");
                System.out.println("O chute foi: " + chute + "\n");
            }
        } while (chute != sorteado);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que quando você lê um valor inválido em `nextInt()` o buffer lido continua armazenado no `Scanner`, causando erro na leitura seguinte, e depois, e depois, e depois ...

Para resolver isso, você deve chamar um `next()` de forma a limpar o buffer antigo em caso de falha:

```
try 
{
    chute = scanner.nextInt();
}
catch (Exception excecao) 
{
     scanner.next();
}
```

Comment: Interessante. Mas não entendi porque o método `next` neste caso não pede o usuário para digitar uma entrada novamente e só limpa o buffer (comprovei que dá certo)? Porque se eu colocar no lugar de `chute = scanner.nextInt();` algo como `umaString = scanner.next();` ele vai pedir ao usuário para entrar uma string.

Comment: Nessa caso sim, basta o `next()` para String.

Comment: Mas porque dentro do catch ele não pede para o usuário entrar com uma string? (Isso acontece apenas dentro do try).

Comment: Porque no `catch` o buffer do Scanner já possui um `\n` armazenado. Então ele já passa do `next()` sem precisar digitar nada. Agora poem dois `next()` no `catch` e veja a diferença.

Answer (score 5):

Para complementar a resposta do @Lucas Nunes:

O valor que fica armazenado no *buffer* do `Scanner` possui o caractere `\n` (enter) que você digitou no final da última leitura de caracteres do teclado, isso faz com que o `Scanner` interprete que você pressionou enter no próximo loop do laço, gerando um loop infinito.

Ao utilizar o `scanner.next();` no `catch`, você "consome" o `\n` que estava armazenado no *buffer*, dessa forma, o *buffer* fica "limpo" para a próxima leitura.

Comment: Interessante. Obrigado pela complementação. Mas como eu consigo ver que o caractere que está empacando a coisa é justamente o *\n*, como posso printar o unicode dele para eu ver essa situação?

Comment: Você vai encontrar essa resposta nesse port do SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817727/access-internal-buffer-length-and-token-match-position-of-flex-scanner